# webbrowser module searching url with absolute path

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-webbrowser

I want to open a website to download resume from it, but following code tries to get to absolute path instead of just url:

```
import webbrowser
soup = BeautifulSoup(webbrowser.open('www.indeed.com/r/Prabhanshu-Pandit/dee64d1418e20069?sp=0'),"lxml")
```

generates the following error:

```
gvfs-open: /home/utkarsh/Documents/Extract_Resume/www.indeed.com/r/Prabhanshu-
Pandit/dee64d1418e20069?sp=0: 
error opening location: Error when getting information for file 
'/home/utkarsh/Documents/Extract_Resume/www.indeed.com/r/Prabhanshu-
Pandit/dee64d1418e20069?sp=0': No such file or directory
```

Clearly it is taking the home address and trying to search that on web which will not be present. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are confusing the usage of Beautiful Soup and webbrowser together. Webbrowser it is not needed to access the page.

From [Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

> Beautiful Soup provides a few simple methods and Pythonic idioms for
>   navigating, searching, and modifying a parse tree: a toolkit for
>   dissecting a document and extracting what you need. It doesn't take
>   much code to write an application

Adapting the [tutorial example](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup) to your task to print the resume in output

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "www.indeed.com/r/Prabhanshu-Pandit/dee64d1418e20069?sp=0"
r  = requests.get("http://" +url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
print soup.find("div", {"id": "resume"})
```

Comment: first thank you for this. Actually I have to do it for multiple resumes and I want to write the response on a txt file... Can you suggest any way to that as well... Thanks in advance

Comment: My suggestion would be to write down a function which get in input an url and print the resume in a file named by the name of the person extracted from the curriculum. After it if you already knows the url you have to work on, store them in a list and after create a cycle which extract one by one the url and call the function.

Comment: but URLs dont have any pattern as such, I mean Its like name of the person followed by some ID, so how can predict next URL